# How to draw the "parallel circuits" sign "//"?

Tags: symbols

I remember seeing the notation "R1 // R2" in electronics books, meaning "(R1^-1 + R2^-1 )^-1", i.e. the resistance of R1 and R2 connected in parallel. What is the correct way of typesetting the "//" sign?

I don't think it's the same as `\parallel`, but I couldn't find any example of the sign.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You want that the double bar behaves like a binary operation, as far as spacing is concerned. So

```
\newcommand{\parallelsum}{\mathbin{\|}}
```

if you like vertical bars, or

```
\newcommand{\parallelsum}{\mathbin{\!/\mkern-5mu/\!}}
```

if you prefer slanted bars.

[image]

Comment: How is `\newcommand{\parallelsum}{\mathbin{\|}}` different from `\parallel`?

Comment: @endolith `\parallel` is defined as a relation symbol; try typesetting `$a\parallel b$` and `$a\mathbin{\parallel}b$` to see the difference: the spaces around a relation symbol are wider than those around a binary operation.

Answer (score 10):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor#Series_and_parallel_resistors) uses `\|` but doesn't distinguish it from `\parallel`. Personally, I'd use `\|` in text and `\parallel` in display math, since the latter has operator spacing.

Comment: `\|` and `\parallel` print the same symbol, but with different spacing: `\|` is ordinary, `\parallel` denotes a binary relation.

Comment: @egreg: It *is* a binary relation, right? So `\parallel` is more semantically correct?

Comment: @endolith: Oh wait.  Maybe it's a binary infix *operator*, which should have closer spacing?  `R_1 \| R_2 = 5` vs testing that two lines are parallel: "`AB \parallel CD` is false"?

Answer (score 8):

IMHO `\parallel` perfectly suits the given situation. Alternatively, you may try `\shortparallel` from the `amssymb` package or `\parallelslant` from `fourier`. From my experience, when two circuit elements are connected in parallel, the formula for total value is written 'R = (R1^-1 + R2^-1 )^-1', as you put it, or 'R = R1 x R2' (using e.g. `\times`), the notation with `\parallel` is less popular with engineers.

Comment: When two components are connected in parallel, the total value is `R_1 \parallel R_2 = {R_1 R_2 \over R_1 + R_2}`.  Writing it using the bars notation can greatly simplify expressions, and keep the relationship clear as symbols are moved around.