# Typesetting a pair of slash symbols to indicate parallel lines

Tags: math-mode, symbols

To indicate that two lines - or line segments - I want to typeset two slash characters. I used `$\overline{AB} \slash\slash \overline{CD}$`.  The space between the slash characters is too much, though.  I could use a thin negative space command `\!`.  I would like to know what is the typical code to do this.

Comment: Does `\parallel` work?

Comment: @Manuel  I wanted the lines slanted - like the slash character.  (In many geometry books, the symbol is two vertical lines just as you would get using `\parallel`.)

Comment: I would use `\parallel` and then *redefine* that command so that it looks different. In any case, you should change your username to something more telling than user666.

Comment: @touhami No, I mean that I would use `\parallel` and then change the definition. `$\vect{AB} \parallel \vect{CD}$` is better than `$\overline{AB} \mathrel{\slash\!\slash} \overline{CD}$` in my opinion; better to use symbolic names.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37912/how-to-draw-the-parallel-circuits-sign help? If you use my answer, you have to change `\mathbin` into `\mathrel`, as the symbol you're looking for is a relation.

Comment: You have the `\parallelslant` and `\nparallelslant` in the `fourier` package, and `\varparallel` and `\nvarparallel in the `ts/px`  fonts. Even if you don't use these fonts, you can define the individual characters as new math binary relation symbols.

Comment: `stmaryrd` has `\sslash` and the same name is used in `unicode-math`.

Comment: @egreg  Yes, `\newcommand{\parallelsum}{\mathbin{\!/\mkern-5mu/\!}}` gives a nice display for the symbol of parallel lines.  I think that the negative thin space `\!` commands bring the slash closer to the pair of letters before and after the symbol.  I remember that `\mathbin` tells `LaTeX` to regard what is being typeset as a binary symbol for spacing.  You already have `\!`, though.  What does `\mkern-5mu` do?

Comment: @user74973 `\mkern-5mu` is responsible for setting the two slashes closer to one another. In my experiment for that application, also removing some space on either side semeed necessary.

Comment: @egreg   How does \mkern and mu compare?  (I did not find `\mkern` in the manual.  I seem to recall that there are 2mu between a character and a binary relation symbol.)  I thought that \mkern is smaller than mu.  I suppose that the distance between the slash characters is the difference between `\mkern` and `5mu`.

Comment: @user74973 18mu make a quad in the symbol font. The usual space between a symbol and a binary relation is 5mu (stretchable to 10mu); between a symbol and a binary operation is 4mu (stretchable to 6mu and shrinkable to zero); `\!` is a negative space of 3mu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To summarise the comments, this symbol is provided by a number of packages:

- `\sslash` from `stmaryrd` and `unicode-math`
- `\parallelslant` from `fourier
- `\varparallel` from `ts/px` fonts

or one can build a macro

```
\newcommand{\parallelsum}{\mathrel{/\mkern-5mu/}}
```